# Data not showing in lightning data table in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-datatable

This is the records

```
allRecords = [
{Name: 'GenePoint', Rating: 'Hot', Industry: 'Energy', NumberOfEmployees: 265, Id: '0065i000006jjyaAAA', …}

{Name: 'GenePoint', Rating: 'Hot', Industry: 'Energy', NumberOfEmployees: 265, Id: '0065i000007gUPOAA2', …}

{Name: 'GenePoint', Rating: 'Hot', Industry: 'Energy', NumberOfEmployees: 265, Id: '0065i000007gUPYAA2', …}
]
```

this is columns

```
allLabels=[
{label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name'}
{label: 'Account Rating', fieldName: 'Rating'}
{label: 'Industry', fieldName: 'Industry'}
{label: 'Employees', fieldName: 'NumberOfEmployees'}
{label: 'Stage', fieldName: 'StageName'}
{label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'Amount'}
{label: 'Lead Source', fieldName: 'LeadSource'}
{label: 'Account ID', fieldName: 'AccountId'}
]
```

This is HTML

```
<lightning-datatable
     key-field="id"
     data={allRecords}
     columns={allLabels}
     hide-checkbox-column=true
>
</lightning-datatable>
```

What I am doing wrong My data columns name and records not showing in lightning data table

Comment: Is there any reason you are not fetching the records through an apex controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly refer this documentation for data and column arrays format.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation

the same code works ( adding missing commas and removing the '...' you had for mentioning rest of the fields)
[image]

Tried your code

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable
     key-field="id"
     data={allRecords}
     columns={allLabels}
     hide-checkbox-column=true
>
</lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

```
import {
    LightningElement
} from 'lwc';

export default class Playground extends LightningElement {

    allRecords = [{
            Name: 'GenePoint',
            Rating: 'Hot',
            Industry: 'Energy',
            NumberOfEmployees: 265,
            Id: '0065i000006jjyaAAA',
        },

        {
            Name: 'GenePoint',
            Rating: 'Hot',
            Industry: 'Energy',
            NumberOfEmployees: 265,
            Id: '0065i000007gUPOAA2',
        },

        {
            Name: 'GenePoint',
            Rating: 'Hot',
            Industry: 'Energy',
            NumberOfEmployees: 265,
            Id: '0065i000007gUPYAA2',
        }
    ];

    allLabels = [{
        label: 'Account Name',
        fieldName: 'Name'
    }, {
        label: 'Account Rating',
        fieldName: 'Rating'
    }, {
        label: 'Industry',
        fieldName: 'Industry'
    }, {
        label: 'Employees',
        fieldName: 'NumberOfEmployees'
    }, {
        label: 'Stage',
        fieldName: 'StageName'
    }, {
        label: 'Amount',
        fieldName: 'Amount'
    }, {
        label: 'Lead Source',
        fieldName: 'LeadSource'
    }, {
        label: 'Account ID',
        fieldName: 'AccountId'
    }];
}
```

Kindly share screenshots or any error messages you encounter to debug more

Comment: index I've added only for the understanding purpose. I've edited the question. Could you please take a look again and tell me the exact issue?

Comment: Updated the answer Mohsin